# Excel VBA - Out of memory when create a dynamic array formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a named range in another cell, say A1. The range is a simple number array (1,2,3,4,5) which I type manually in C3:G3, and I named the range as MyArray.

When I run my code, Excel will pop up a window said 'Out of Memory'. Is there any way to address this problem?

```
Sub MyArray()

Range("A1").Formula2 = "=MyArray"


End Sub
```

Comment: Are the C1:G1 and range("A1") on the same sheet?

Comment: My guess is that since they are on the same sheet you are actually getting a spill error.  Since it is a horizontal array and you are trying to put that array in A1 it will fill A1:E1 which overlaps the values in the named range.

Comment: @Scott Craner Yes they are in the same sheet

Comment: Then see my second comment.  change the target range to a group of 5 horizontal cell that are truly empty.

Comment: @Scott Craner Sorry my typo, the named range is C3 to G3, so no overlaps

Comment: if you put the formula in the cell directly without vba, do you get an error?

Comment: Basically I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Do you have other code in a worksheet change event that could be causing the issue?

Comment: No if I manually do the formula, it'll be all good. However I need to use VBA in my context

Comment: No i wrote the code in a module, normal environment

Comment: That does not change if the sheet has a worksheet change event on it.  That code in itself will not cause this issue.  I cannot reproduce.  There is something else that we do not know that is causing this.

Comment: `Range` implicitly cites `ActiveSheet`. You should qualify what sheet you are working with like: `Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula2 = "=MyArray"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MyArray()


Range("A1").Formula2 = "=R[2]C[2]:R[2]C[6]"


End Sub
```

But that will only put the C3:G3 in the A1 cell like you wanted. However when I just ran a macro replacing "=R[2]C[2]:R[2]C[6]" with "=C3:G3" and using A20 or something as a target cell, it worked just fine.